# HTML tag regex doesen't work

Tags: java, regex

Why this code doesen't return "" ?
What regex should I use to replace all tags from a html file?

```
x = x.replaceAll("<.*>", "<h3><a href=\"#\">current community</a></h3>");
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Only Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Seriously, don't parse html with regex

Comment: Then what should I use? I don't really want to parse it, I'm not interested in the content of the HTML tags, I want to remove all tags from a HTML file.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to remove the HTML tags in order to obtain the text

Comment: @CosminMihai Very bad solution, as you should use a HTML parser for that, but did you try with `<.+?>`. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/DLyZ4j)

Comment: I want to remove the HTML tags, not to parse them, I'm trying to obtain raw data, please read the question I want to "REPLACE" with "" meaning that I want to delete them

Comment: @CosminMihai A HTML parser is able to remove all tags in a much cleaner way than with regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: **You shouldn't use regex to parse html.**

But, if you insist, try a

Find:  `"<(?:(?:/?\\w+\\s*/?)|(?:\\w+\\s+(?:(?:(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\")|(?:'[\\S\\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\\s*/?)|\\?[\\S\\s]*?\\?|(?:!(?:(?:DOCTYPE[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:\\[CDATA\\[[\\S\\s]*?\\]\\])|(?:--[\\S\\s]*?--)|(?:ATTLIST[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ENTITY[\\S\\s]*?)|(?:ELEMENT[\\S\\s]*?))))>"`
Replace: ""

```
 <
 (?:
      (?:
           /? 
           \w+ 
           \s* 
           /? 
      )
   |  
      (?:
           \w+ 
           \s+ 
           (?:
                (?:
                     (?: " [\S\s]*? " )
                  |  (?: ' [\S\s]*? ' )
                )
             |  (?: [^>]*? )
           )+
           \s* 
           /? 
      )
   |  
      \?
      [\S\s]*? 
      \?
   |  
      (?:
           !
           (?:
                (?:
                     DOCTYPE
                     [\S\s]*? 
                )
             |  (?:
                     \[CDATA\[
                     [\S\s]*? 
                     \]\]
                )
             |  (?:
                     --
                     [\S\s]*? 
                     --
                )
             |  (?:
                     ATTLIST
                     [\S\s]*? 
                )
             |  (?:
                     ENTITY
                     [\S\s]*? 
                )
             |  (?:
                     ELEMENT
                     [\S\s]*? 
                )
           )
      )
 )
 >
```

Comment: Oh, hang on, I'll include that.

Comment: @CosminMihai- Ok, added doctype. It's a little xml-ish.

Answer (score 4):

> I want to remove the HTML tags

You could simply use a HTML parsing library such as [`JSoup`](http://jsoup.org/). Here is an example

```
Document doc = 
     Jsoup.parse("<html><h3><a href=\"#\">current community</a></h3></html>");
System.out.println(doc.text());
```

Output:

```
current community
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution later, for the moment I need something fast to use, Jsoup needs to be downloaded I think.

Answer (score 3):

I will agree with everyone else that attempting to use a regex to parse HTML is a bad idea.  (And I think that's true even if all you're doing is removing the tags; things like comments and `!CDATA` will complicate any attempt at a simple solution.)  However, I think it's useful to explain why your solution didn't produce the results you expected (because this applies to other situations where regexes are more appropriate).

By default, the `*` and `+` quantifiers are *greedy*, which means they will match as many characters as they can.  Thus, in your example:

```
x = x.replaceAll("<.*>", "<h3><a href=\"#\">current community</a></h3>");
```

I think this is what you meant:

```
String x = "<h3><a href=\"#\">current community</a></h3>";
x = x.replaceAll("<.*>", "");
```

When the matching engine searches for your pattern, it finds `<` as the first character of `x`.  Then it looks for a sequence of zero or more characters that can be anything, followed by `>`.  But since it's a greedy quantifier, if there's a choice of more than one `>` it can pick, it will pick the one that makes `.*` match the *longest* possible string.  In your case, that means that it will pick the `>` which is the last character of `x`.  The effect is that the entire string is replaced by `""`.

To make it match the *smallest* possible string, add `?` to make it a "reluctant quantifier":

```
x = x.replaceAll("<.*?>", "");
```

Another solution is to tell the matcher not to include `>` when matching "any character":

```
x = x.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
```

`[^>]` means "match any character except `>`.  For HTML/XML/SGML, the regex I would choose is neither of the above, since you shouldn't use regular expressions to parse complex structures like that.